# Keep HSPA+ connection up

Tags: linux, networking

I am developing an app that runs periodically some network test under a 3G connection provided from a 3G dongle. The problem is that when you try to do some pings or initiallize a download, you have some latency due to the WCDMA/HSPA+ change.

I know that there's an app on Windows that keep the HSPA+ mode ON called HSPA locker. The question is for an app with the same funcionallity at linux.

Regards!